# Where is the ruby module self.included and self.extended behaviour documented?

Tags: ruby, mixins

I was looking at the [ruby mixin](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/) blog post, and it says that when a module is included in a class its `self.included()` method is called.

My question is, where is this behaviour officially documented? I can't seem to locate it on the ruby-docs.org website or the pickaxe.

Answer (score 10):

While it's not on [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org) for some reason, `included` actually is documented. Running `ri Module.included` in the terminal provides this:

> ```
> included( othermod )
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Callback invoked whenever the receiver is included in another module
>   or class. This should be used in preference to `Module.append_features`
>   if your code wants to perform some action when a module is included in
>   another.
>
> ```
> module A
>   def A.included(mod)
>     puts "#{self} included in #{mod}"
>   end
> end
> module Enumerable
>   include A
> end
> ```

This documentation can be found in the [Ruby source in `object.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_194/object.c#L719). Sadly, `Module.extended` is not documented.

Comment: `Module.extended` is exactly like `included`, except that it runs when you call `extend some_module` instead of when you call `include some_module`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's not on the RubyDoc website because it's a private method, and private methods aren't currently displayed.

People are aware of this issue, but they haven't yet worked out how to handle methods that are private even though they aren't implementation details.

I've created a bug report at http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6381

Comment: Interesting that it's visible via `ri`, though. Good catch on private methods not being on Ruby Doc! Definitely unfortunate, be nice if they were "folded away" by default, but could still be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

seems only public methods are documented

Answer (score 0):

Both are documented on page 556 of the second edition of pickaxe (covering Ruby 1.8). The documentation there looks just like the result of `ri Module.included` that Andrew Marshall posted, so I suspect that section of the book was automatically generated. If it's been dropped from later editions of pickaxe, then it might be a result of the same bug that keeps it from showing up on [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/).